# Conditionally set v-model in Vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, data-binding, eslint

I have a series of inputs that could be either checkboxes or radio buttons, depending on a value in the `data` of my vue component.

In particular, I have a `Question` component, and questions may accept only one answer or multiple answers. I have a `selected_answers` array in my `data`, and I was thinking I could have the checkboxes target it as their `v-model`, while the radio buttons could target `selected_answers[0]`. This way, I don't have to copy-paste che input elements and just change their type and v-model.

So, my solution would look something like this:

```
<input
    :type="question.accepts_multiple answers ? 'checkbox' : 'radio'"
    :id="'ans-' + answer.id"
    :value="answer.id"
    v-model="question.accepts_multiple_answers ? selected_answers : selected_answers[0]"
/>
```

However, eslint complains about my code:

```
'v-model' directives require the attribute value which is valid as LHS
```

What's a way I can accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Btw, besides `v-model`, you can use any regular ES6 code pretty much everywhere. Example of valid code: ```:id="`ans-${answer.id}`"```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up figuring it out by myself.

```
<input
    :type="question.accepts_multiple_answers ? 'checkbox' : 'radio'"
    :id="'ans-' + answer.id"
    :value="question.accepts_multiple_answers ? answer.id : [answer.id]"
    v-model="selected_answers"
/>
```

Comment: As told in my answer, here you will have basically 2 `value`. Maybe remove `v-model` and change it to an `@input` with something like `@input=selected_answers = $event.value`.

Comment: not sure what you mean by having 2 `value`. the official vue docs show examples where there are both `v-model` and `value` on the same elements

Comment: Depends of the type of input. For a text, there is no real point keeping a `v-model` IMO, but you do you. Not erroring this way gonna say.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use any *advanced* code inside of `v-model` (just a basic string), you could export `question.accepts_multiple_answers ? selected_answers : selected_answers[0]` to a `computed` and plug the `computed` to the `v-model`.

If you need to have a setter, you will need to write a [computed setter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter), this looks like this

```js
computed: {
  fullName: {
    // getter
    get() {
      return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName
    },
    // setter
    set(newValue) {
      var names = newValue.split(' ')
      this.firstName = names[0]
      this.lastName = names[names.length - 1]
    }
  }
}
```

---

Meanwhile, since `v-model` is just some [sugar syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Basic-Usage), you could also replace it with usual `:value` + `@input` (depending of the type of the field). I do prefer to use those 2 than `v-model` nowadays, especially for the kind of limitations that you do have right now.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do it like that.

I recommend you to set up a variable when loading your component like that:

```
data()
{
    return {
        model_string: '',
    }
}
```

Then you give your variable some values depending on your own conditions

```
created() {
   if (your.first.condition) {
    this.model_string = your.value;
   } else if (your.other.condition) {
    this.model_string = your.value;
   }
}
```

After this, you can use it in your view as you wish

```
<input v-model="model_string" ..... // your attributes>
```